# Piwik API how to get daily visits for 7 days

Tags: api, analytics, matomo

I'm trying to get daily visits from my instance of piwik for every day in the week.

Currently this query is returning the sum of all my visits for the entire week. Is there any way to separate this out into days?

```
http://piwikexample.com/?module=API&method=VisitsSummary.getVisits&idSite=1&period=range&date=2011-08-18,2011-08-25&format=json&token_auth=#########
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually figured it out. What I was missing is:

lastX for the last X periods including today (eg &date=last10&period=day would return an entry for each of the last 10 days including today). This is relative to the website timezone.

From
http://piwik.org/docs/analytics-api/reference/#API

Answer (score 1):

## Piwik's documentation isn't the best

I had to use the old-fashioned **trial-and-error** approach.

### There are 3 ways, if you have `period` set right:

1. **lastX**

   - This returns the last X days, including current day.
   - **i.e.** `&period=day&date=last10`
2. **previousX**

   - This returns the previous X days, excluding today.
   - **i.e.** `&period=day&date=previous10`
3. **date range**

   - `&period=day&date=2011-08-18,2011-08-25`

Just make sure you use `period=day` instead of `period=range` and you'll be good to go. See this note from the API:

> Note: if you set 'period=range' to request data for a custom date range, the API will return the sum of data for the specified date range.

**Reference:** [Reporting API **(date)** section](https://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/reporting-api)